# saving the matrix and the plot figures

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab program that generate a matrix f (which is 3 column and 100 raw)  then the program plot the 1st column with second one and third one 
every time I change a specific variable the matrix values changes and the plot changes 
if I made a for loop to generate different matrices with different plots how could I made the program to save the matrix and the plot figures each loop with different names in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

You can [save](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/save.html) the matrices inside the loop or place them in a cell array and save that after the loop. To save figures to file you can use [print](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/print.html).

Something along these lines:

```
for ii=foo:bar
    mat=...;
    fig=figure;    

    % somehow create matrix mat and figure fig;
    save(['quux',num2str(ii),'.mat'],mat);
    print(fig,['quux',num2str(ii)]);
end
```